# Third order differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering if there were known methods for solving this type of differential equations ?

$$x^2y'''+3xy''+2xy'+2y=0$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $y(x)=\frac1x$ is a solution

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the order of the DE:
$$x^2y'''+3xy''+2xy'+2y=0$$
$$(x^2y'')'+(xy')'-y'+2(xy)'=0$$
Integrate:
$$x^2y''+xy'+(2x-1)y=C_1$$
Now it's a second order DE. Then use reduction of order or series solution.

Comment: This is nice !. but, how can I further reduce the order as you mentioned ?

Comment: @Lolzyto you can use Frobenius method. WA gives a solution in terms of Bessel functions of second kind...

Comment: what do you think of this ? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+y%27%27+%2B+xy%27%2B%282x-1%29y%3D+a

Comment: @Lolzyto  Very complicated..The solution to the homogeneous equation can surely be found by Frobenius method https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+y%27%27+%2B+xy%27%2B%282x-1%29y%3D+0

Comment: But the problem at hand isn't homogeneous as it has C1 ?

Comment: Yes but it's a tradition in DE to first solve  the homogeneous equation then solve the inhomogeneous DE..@Lolzyto

Comment: After solving the homogeneous one to get the homogeneous solution. After that the general solution is $$y_H+d$$, where d is a constant. Now, we should substitute back in the original equation. This gives me an equation having four constants (two from the homogeneous solution, C1 and d) and bessel functions. If I get the relation between C1 and d, won't I converge to this solution in the end :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+y%27%27+%2B+xy%27%2B%282x-1%29y%3D+C1 ?

Comment: Four constants ? Thats 'impossible it's a third order equation so three constants are needed @Lolzyto

Comment: @Lolzyto If the solution(s) of 2nd order linear ode is known, then it can be used the method of variation, or the method of Green-functions. For the 2nd order case these can be find with derived formula in (standard) university textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

The [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*y%28x%29%27%27%27%20%2B3*x*y%28x%29%27%27%20%2B2*x*y%28x%29%27%20%2B2*y%28x%29%3D0).
The general method is the Frobenius-method, trying to find the solution in the form of generalized power series.